# How to remove DuckDuckGo browser from ArrowOS?

Tags: applications, rooting, boot

I recently installed ArrowOS on my phone but it comes with the duckduckgo browser which really annoys me with constant notifications and overall I hate it.

How do I remove it safely from the system so that I don't get stuck in a bootloop?

I had already tried what @Firelord suggested in the comments before opening this thread but got stuck in bootloop. I have encountered similar situations with other devices too and will appreciate any help I get, whether they be step by step tutorials or general advice on how to approach this kind of problem.

Needlessly to say I have root access and have Magisk installed.

Comment: Why don't you just install a different web browser make it the default web browser and WebView (the latter in the developer options). Then the default browser is just ignored.

Comment: That way I don't learn anything, hence I want to mess around with the apps that startup at boot to really understand how android works. I have, in fact, already downloaded brave and made it the default browser on my system.

Comment: Have you also made it the default WebView app? Otherwise DuckDuckGo my be still used by apps which display web sites via WebView.

Comment: There is only 1 option called Android System Webview and then the version number of the webview implementation with a blue chromium logo before all the text. I installed amaze file manager and apparently I can uninstall system level apps with it. Do you think I should do it?